# Storing a large number of objects of similar but different classes in the DB

Tags: .net, sql-server, inheritance, design-patterns, single-table-inheritance

I'm dealing with a lot of similar `Event` classes that need to be stored in a DB.
They all inherit from `AbstractEvent` and implement the interface `IEvent`. The main difference lies in their properties:

```
RainStartsEvent
    TimeRainStarted: Time
    LitresOfRainPerSquareMeter: Float
    RainTemperature: Integer

SunUpEvent
    TimeSunUp: Time
    PersonWhoSawItFirst: Integer
    Brightness: Float
    SongOfTheDay: String

 SomeOtherEvent
    UniquePropery1: someType
    StandardProperty: someType
```

and so on. There will be dozens or even hundreds of `Events` and they potentially have nothing in common except what they inherit form `AbstactEvent` and implement from `IEvent`.

Now I need to store those objects in the database. I thought about Single-Table-Inheritance or Table-Per-Hierarchy-Inheritance but it doesn't make sense because of the large and ever increasing number of `Events`. I would end up with a table that exceeds 255 fields.

The other idea I had is to store all `Events` in a single table and all their properties in a different table, one property per row with a foreign key to the `Events` table. However, that would mean I have to store them all as string and do a lot of (de)serializing, i.e. this may not perform very well in a system with a large number of `Events`.

Do I need to use the .NET Object Serialization to make this perform better? Would that help?

What else is possible? There must be a more standard solution for this problem, some sort of best practice or design pattern. Any ideas?

UPDATE: The data needs to be read continuously, and updated rarely. A record is going to be read in full, no ordering, where clause, conditional statements or indexes in the DB

Comment: You could use an XML column to hold these additional columns.  That wouldn't be ideal if you wanted to query on those columns, but if you only filter/sort on the common columns it may make sense.

Comment: You should say what your needs are with the database (indexing, searching, etc.) as several answers indicate.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you just want to store the data. The thing you didn't say if you care about indexing, querying, etc. on those data?

You could conver them to JSON and stroe them as string in MS SQL Server (or most of the RDBMSes out there), but if you have the luxyry or luck of having a PostreSQL it has native support for [JSON data types](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/datatype-json.html) with some [querying mechanism](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-json.html) as well.

The other solution - if the solution is more about data and not using a relation model is acceptable - would be to go with a Document Database like MongoDb or RavenDB so that you don't care (or limited) by the limitations that the relation databases, again for the most part - impose on you.

Answer (score 0):

It really sounds like you are needing something other than a traditional RDBMS as you aren't doing anything with the data outside of set and get. So you should be looking into the various NoSQL options.

However, (just to have it stated), if you are going to use SQL Server:

- If you go the unstructured route, then use an XML field instead of an NVARCHAR holding JSON data. There is no inherent support for parsing JSON.
- If you go the structured route, please see my answers on DBA.StackExchage on this exact topic:

  - [Don't know how to transform variable entity into relational table](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/80951/dont-know-how-to-transform-variable-entity-into-relational-table)
  - [How to Implement Different Object Types as Similar Tables?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/84109/how-to-implement-different-object-types-as-similar-tables)